# Debian 10: External monitor stopped working (works on boot, stops after log in)

Tags: drivers, debian

My external monitor stopped working out of nowhere. 
I use a Dell Inspiron 15 with Debian 10, after a few months the external monitor was no longer beign recognized.

I tested the monitor (with the same HDMI cable) in another computer and it worked fine.
Couldn't test my notebook in another monitor yet HOWEVER when I boot the PC the [same] external monitor works up to the log in page.
After I log in with my user the monitor go black and warns about no signal. [So it isn't my hdmi entry]

I read somewhere it **coul be related to battery saving mode**, but couldn't find anything related in the settings.

Also tried this solution:
https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/External-Monitor-not-working-Ubuntu-nvidia/td-p/6241315

But couldn't find the mentioned `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf` file. 
(There is only `fbdev-blacklist.conf`, `aliases.conf`, `systemd.conf`)
and none of those file has the line:

```
# Set value to 0 to disable modesetting
# options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

my `xrandr` return: (with the monitor connected or not)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND2 connected 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1280x720      59.65*+
```

my `lspci` return:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

What else can I do?